# Unable to send the email in office 365 in C# error

Tags: office365

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("admin@xxxxxxxx.in");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("sales@xxxxxxxx.in"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Test Subject";
mailMessage.Body = "Testing Office365 Email";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@xxxxxxxx.in", "xxxxxxxx");
client.Port = 465;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

> Getting following error message.
> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
> The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139
> Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant."
> Please help me to resolve the issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable SMTP authentication-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission#enable-smtp-auth-for-specific-mailboxes

Comment: Joel Pusanur - I bought the domain and email id in godaddy when i try to go to Microsoft 365 admin center its navigating to godaddy page and couldn't find any options like enabling.

Comment: Go to admin.microsoft.com and login with admin account. https://youtu.be/Ydalru8_TmY

Comment: Joel Pusanur - Finally, I,m able to send the email using EASendMail nuget package. Thanks.